# Buttons in an AbsoluteLayout overlap other objects on Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have an odd thing happening with last Xamarin update and I am not sure what to do about it.

I have a view

```
<ContentView.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100">
            <Button x:Name="BackgroundButton" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" />
            <Image x:Name="Icon" InputTransparent="True" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Margin="20,15,20,25"/>
            <Label x:Name="CountLabel" Style="{StaticResource HubButtonLabel}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"  />
            <Label x:Name="ButtonLabel" Style="{StaticResource HubButtonLabel}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"  />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Is basically just a button wrapper, with some extra icons, and text. I have a few of these in the project of different layouts and styles. Until the last update they worked fine. Now the button renders overtop of everything else. I can confirm that by setting the button color to something semi transparent.

This only happens on Android, it still works as expected on ios
Anyone have a fix for that? or do I need to rework all these views?

Update - So while this isn't really a fix, but also kind of is. If I swap out the `Button` for an `ImageButton` - they work again as expected on both platforms.

Bug perhaps with button on Android?

Comment: Did you try to downgrade XF to previous version and check buttons behavior? If this is a bug you should report it to XF github. I had similar problem with text not being centered on new release.

Comment: Yes, when I initially encountered it I downgraded to be able to publish an update but now I am trying to find if the issues is my end or something on the forms end. I am also trying to find an answer xamarin.forms forums as well.

Comment: I reproduced your question. you could report it to XF github.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer on another forum. - Apparently it is a known bug with an easy fix, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/394729

Put
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers");
Before the xamarin init in Main Activity Oncreate.